# How to get all animated properties of the layer in a After Effects script?

Tags: properties, keyframe, after-effects

The subject is clear from the header.
I need to alter all keyframes of all properties of the particular layer.
So for the access to keyframe in AE script comes through the property it animate, am I need to traverse through all possible properies, the layer could have?
Or the layer object has a function like: "allKeyFrames()" or "AllAnimatedProperties()" - the way shortcut "U" works )))
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop through properties, but you can be helped by things like numKeys, which will tell you whether a property has keys or not, and perhaps propertyDepth, and also isModified. See scripting guide (esp. pages 124 and 149).

Comment: What's the best way to iterate over all properties? I do not see a way of getting a list of all properties and it seems you need to reference them by name.

Comment: I believe there is a static number of properties (15). You could loop though by getting the properties by index `layer.property(index)`